# How do I find the commutator subgroup of $A_n$ for $n \ge 5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I understand it can't be trivial since $A_n$ is not abelian. Further, $A_n$ is simple so the only option remaing is that $[A_n, A_n] = A_n$. Is this correct?

Comment: looks right to me

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but you can also prove this without knowing that $A_n$ is simple.

Comment: You can prove, for example, that every $3$-cycle is a commutator.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Can you explain please? I'd like to know.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Is this correct: $(a b c)=(a b) (a c) (a b) (a c)$? But then, the 2-cycles aren't elements of $A_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you want to show $(a\ b\ c) \in [A_n,A_n]$, where $n \geq 5$. Take $[x,y]$ where $x = (a\ c\ b)$, and $y = (b\ c)(d\ e)$.

Then $[x,y] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = x(yx^{-1}y^{-1})$.

Now $yx^{-1}y$ is the conjugate of $x^{-1}$ by $y$, that is:

$yx^{-1}y = y(a\ b\ c)y^{-1} = (y(a)\ y(b)\ y(c)) = (a \ c\ b) = x$.

(*note: $y = y^{-1}$ so it doesn't matter for this example if you compose left-to-right, or right-to-left).

Hence $[x,y] = x^2 = (a\ b\ c)$, as desired. Note we need the two extra letter $d$ and $e$ to "pad out" $y$ (which would otherwise be a transposition), so this doesn't work for $A_4$ and $A_3$.

If you know the $3$-cycles generate $A_n$  this shows that for $n \geq 5$, that $[A_n,A_n] = A_n$ (in other words, it's "very non-abelian").