# Finite group where all the elements are commutators

Tags: group-theory

Is there a finite group of order greater than $1$, where all the elements are commutators?

I thought about this question once, but I couldn't think of a single example. Obviously, such a group must be perfect.

Perhaps the following fact can be used somehow:

$g \in G$ is commutator iff $$\sum\limits_{\chi \in Irr(G)} \frac{\chi(g)}{\chi(1)} \neq 0$$

Comment: By Ore's Conjecture (now a theorem), every element of every finite nonabelian simple group is a commutator.

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group, let $H$ be the commutator subgroup, then $H$ is normal in $G$, and the quotient group $G/H$ is abelian. If $G$ is a nonabelian simple group, then it has no normal subgroups other than itself and the one-element subgroup, so its commutator subgroup must be the whole group. So any nonabelian simple group should do, e.g., the alternating group $A_n$ for $n\ge5$.

Now, the question is whether that means all elements are commutators. There are finite groups where there are products of commutators that aren't themselves commutators, but the smallest example is a group of order $96$, so for $A_5$ it must be the case that all the elements are commutators. The result about groups of order $96$ has been mentioned on previous questions about commutators on this website, e.g., [Derived subgroup where not every element is a commutator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroup-where-not-every-element-is-a-commutator)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510680/how-do-i-find-the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-n-for-n-ge-5

Comment: Yes, that's right, I somehow even completely forgot about this example. Thank you very much!

Comment: And see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7811/derived-subgroup-where-not-every-element-is-a-commutator

Comment: @Nicky, I cited that post in my answer.

Comment: Ah apologies, Gerry! Anyway +1 from me for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can certainly recommend reading the overview paper *On Commutators in Groups* by L.C. Kappe and R.F. Morse, which appeared in the second volume of [Groups St. Andrews](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Groups-St-Andrews-2005%3A-On-commutators-in-groups-Kappe-Morse/a29cf9f40090957f790d2f65ddd70ff0bf69ea19) 2005, p. 531-558. It contains a lot of very interesting information and 76 relevant references.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think it will be very helpful for me